# Disable RPM compression

Tags: maven, jar, compression, rpm

I'm having a few issues with a spring-boot jar file that I have packaged in an RPM using the maven RPM plugin. The issue is it won't run if it has been compressed (which is what happens when it the jar file gets packaged in an RPM.)

I was wondering if there is any way to turn off/disable this RPM compression in a similar way that you can do in a zip file. I have already tried adding 
%define _source_payload w0.gzdio
%define _binary_payload w0.gzdio
to my .spec file (through the rpm maven plugin) but the jar file is still being compressed.

Comment: rpm uses compression only inside its package, after installation everything should be uncompressed again. If that is not the case, then the cause lies in Maven, not in rpm.

Answer (score 0):

RPM building does some post-processing on JAR files. See `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars` for specifics.

See also: [Packaging:Java](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Java) and [this old mailing list post](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-java-list/2008-September/msg00040.html).